# Reactjs adding the selected react-bootstrap tab key # to the current URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap

I have component contain "React Bootstrap Tab", i want if user select any of these three tabs , to add to current url:-

> http://localhost:3000/account

the selected tab key name, so the url change like this:-

> http://localhost:3000/account#messages

I have tried by using props.history.push in onSelect function but nothing happened.

```
import React from "react";
import KhatmaTable from "../components/Account/KhatmasTable";
import Square from "../components/Account/Square";
import Messages from "../components/Account/Messages";
import { Tabs, Tab } from "react-bootstrap";

class Account extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: {},
      khatmas: [],
      selectedKey: this.props.location.hash
        ? this.props.location.hash.substring(1)
        : "home",
    };
  }

  render() {
    const count = [this.state.khatmats];
    console.log(this.state.user);
    console.log(this.state.user.khatmas ? this.state.user.khatmas.length : "");
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-body">
          <Tabs
            id="controlled-tab-example"
            activeKey={this.state.selectedKey}
            onSelect={(k) => {
              this.setState({ selectedKey: k });
              this.props.history.replace = "account" + "#" + k;
            }}
          >
            <Tab eventKey="home" title="home">
              <div className="row">
                <Square />
              </div>
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey="khatmat" title="profile">
              <KhatmaTable />
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey="messages" title="messages">
              <Messages />
            </Tab>
          </Tabs>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Account;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write below function before render and modify the value part `?tab=${key}` inside replace function as per your need.

```
handleSelect = (key) => {
    this.setState({ key });
    this.props.history.replace({
        hash: `${key}`
    })
}
```

Inside Tabs, Add function name as shown below

```
<Tabs onSelect={this.handleSelect} >
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This makes sense when toggling tab buttons. But reverse seems does not working.

Answer (score 2):

Just if anyone need the functionality answered above by @Niraj as a react hook.

```
import React from "react";
//import bootstrap components
import Tabs from 'react-bootstrap/Tabs';
import Tab from 'react-bootstrap/Tab';

const TabComponent = (props) => {
    //set state from url hash
    const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState(props.location.hash.substring(1));

    const handleSelect = (e) => {
        //set state
        setSelectedTab(e);
        //update url
        props.history.replace({
            hash: `${e}`
        });
    }

    return (
        //set active key, if no url hash set default to home
        <Tabs 
            activeKey={selectedTab ? selectedTab : 'home'}
            onSelect={(e) => handleSelect(e)}
        >
            <Tab eventKey="home" title="home">
            ....
            </Tab>
            <Tab eventKey="about" title="about">
            ....
            </Tab>
        </Tabs>
    );
}
export default TabComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const handleTabSelect = (key) => {
    setActiveTabPrimary(key);
    // Append the selected tab key to the URL hash
    window.location.hash = key;
};
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question will make it more useful for others in the future. Please consider updating your answer with some explanatory notes. Thanks